# Ruby on Rails/AJAX: How can I refresh page on successful submit or display error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to rails and I am trying to configure my form to submit a request via ajax. My page has a popup using bootstrap that has the form.

If the data is valid, then I would like the page to redirect to the original page ('new' action). If there is a duplicate member (model returned false on save), then I want to display this error message:

"You already exist in our system or your e-mail address is a duplicate. Please sign in if you have registered before."

Here is the view (only some):

```
 <%= form_for(@person, url: {controller: "sign_ins"},html: {class: "form-signup",
                   id: "signupform"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <p id="info_text" class="lead">Please enter the information below to register.</p>
      <div id = "err_msg"></div>
      <%= render("shared/companylist") %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control fieldBottomMargin", placeholder: "First Name", required: true %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control fieldBottomMargin", placeholder: "Last Name", required: true %>
      <%= f.phone_field :phone, class: "form-control fieldBottomMargin",
            placeholder: "Phone Number (No Dashes)", required: true, pattern: "([0-9]{10})" %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control fieldBottomMargin", placeholder: "E-mail", required: true%>
      <%= f.button "Register", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block", id: "btnsubmit" %>
    <% end %>
```

This is my controller create action, which I don't know if it is correct:

```
def create
@person = Person.new(person_params) #Call 'strong paremeters' method.
respond_to do |format|
  if @person.save
   format.html {redirect_to home_url}
   format.js {}
  else
  @err_msg = "You already exist in our system or your e-mail address is a duplicate. 
                   Please sign in if you have registered before."
  format.js {}
  end
end
```

end

and here is my (failed) js file, which I can't find out how to configure.

```
 $('#err_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><%= j @err_message %></div>');
```

have been working on this for hours. appreciate any help. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your create.js.erb file, you can use jquery to display that.

```
$('#err_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><%= j @err_message %></div>');
```

To redirect if the object is saved, do the following in your controller:

```
  format.js { render js: 'window.location.href = "/your_desired_path";' }
```

These should be enough!

Comment: Thank you! The error message displays perfectly. However, I replaced the format.js with your code to this:

format.js { 'window.location.href = "<%= home_url %>";' }

but actually my popup shows up on the form without a message (just a red-colored div). Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't. Is the code correct? I embedded ruby: format.js { 'window.location.href = "<%= home_url %>";' }

Edit: I also put that code in the 'else' statement. No redirects either.

Comment: oh sorry a little mistakes. Now check the updated the format.js. This will must work!